# Php TAX substract & add back

Tags: php, shopping-cart, tax

I have a shop where the client enters the product price with the tax in his country. When i save it i need to remove the tax and keep only the base.

When i calculate the tax back for the clients from the same country in some cases the total price will be different with 0.01 , 0.03 then the original price.

I tried to calculate with 2 to 4 digits but it never works on all cases.

> Ex: price with tax = 157, tax is 7.7% => base = 145.78 and tax amount 11.22

When i calculate the tax to the previous price base i get this:

> Base: 145.78 , tax is 7.7% => 11.23 = price is 157.01

Php code i use:

```
$baseprice = round($fullprice / (1+($taxperc/100)),2);
```

On the frontend:

```
$tax = round($baseprice * ( $taxperc / 100 ),2);
$total = $tax + $baseprice;
```

Anyone have a suggestion about how to fix this ?

Thanks!

Update: after some research I found a solution is to use round with PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN

Update2: first solution doesnt work. 1-9 works fine, 10 -tax + tax =10.01

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2860432/457268

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: You might also want to use a money library, e.g. http://moneyphp.org/en/latest/

Comment: Will check the money library. Thanks

Comment: IMO the Serverside should store both the base price and added tax. Rounding issues will not be avoidable otherwise as to how floats work.

Comment: I store only the base price because the tax rate changes from time to time, and the old tax will have no use.

Comment: You store only the current base price on the product. Yet on the actual order a buyer bought you then can store both the price and tax applied when bought. Prices and tax rates may change, an order once issued should not.

Comment: On the order of course I store both, but in the product record i store only the base price.

Answer (score 0):

Today's solution would be to work on the back with full number of digits ( for base price, tax and total ) and only when display for user to round it. :)

Answer (score -1):

Seems ( not 100% sure yet, i need to test more ) a solution is to use the banker's rounding PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN

```
$baseprice = round($fullprice / (1+($taxperc/100)),2 , PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
$tax = round($baseprice * ( $taxperc / 100 ),2 , PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
$total = $tax + $baseprice;
```